# Docker build works via CLI but not from Compose (referring to same Dockerfile)

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I have a Dockerfile that runs a small Python app.  The Dockerfile as follows:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
COPY . .
WORKDIR /mqtt_api
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "api:app"]
```

When I build the above with `docker build --tag <name> .` in the Dockerfile directory, it builds fine and runs fine.  I run with via CLI with (note bash is just for troubleshooting):

```
docker run -d -it -p "8000:8000" <env vars> <image> bash
```

However, when I build from a docker-compose file (same dir as Dockerfile) with this yaml:

```
api:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: api
    ports:
        - "8000:8000"
```

I get an error saying one of my Python dependencies in `requirements.txt` needs to be imported.

The weirdest thing about that is installs before this specific module work fine too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does your `WORKDIR` appear after the `COPY`? Like this, you are copying the `requirements.txt` to a different folder than the one where you run `pip install`.

Comment: @DannyB I guess I don't understand the perspective of `WORKDIR`. Is it supposed to be the perspective of the host or the container (image)?

Comment: Almost everything in `Dockerfile` is from the perspective of the image, except the first argument in `COPY` and `ADD`. Since you are doing `COPY . .` I am assuming you intend to copy your host's current directory to the `/mqtt_api` dir. Move the `WORKDIR` to be before it, see if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @DannyB Okay did it.  Same problem, unfortunately.  I'm not sure it's a Dockerfile problem if it runs fine via the CLI and not via docker-compose, right?

Comment: @DannyB I was able to get it to work by using `image` with the already-built image instead of `build`ing it on the fly.  I won't want to do that, however.  Is there some kind of image-caching that docker-compose does where it wouldn't actually build my newly modified Dockerfile?